# Загрузка модуля по адресу была заблокирована из-за неразрешенного MIME-типа («text/plain»)

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Есть сервер на flask/python, структура файлов приблизительно следующая:

```
./
  app.py
  template/
    download.html
  static/
    download.js
    modules/
      pyInit.js
```

Содержимое файлов:
download.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="../">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/download.css">
    <script type="module" src="static/download.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/streamsaver@2.0.3/StreamSaver.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.3/full/pyodide.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

download.js:

```
import * as Python from './modules/pyInit'

document.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        main()
    }
})

... // (Много функций)

async function main() {
    await Python.load();
    ... // (Некоторые getElementById и другие вызовы)
}
```

pyInit.js:

```
let pyodide;
let micropip;
let bytes;
let lzma;
let hashlib;
let modules = {};

async function load() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        loadPyodide().then((pyodide_result) => {
            pyodide = pyodide_result;
            pyodide.loadPackage("micropip").then((result) => {
                micropip = pyodide.pyimport("micropip");
                pip("lzma").then((module) => {
                    lzma = module;
                    hashlib = pyodide.pyimport("hashlib");
                    bytes = pyodide.globals.get("bytes");
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

function pip(modulename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            micropip.install(modulename).then((result) => {
                let module = pyodide.pyimport(modulename)
                modules[modulename] = module;
                resolve(module);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}

function run(command) {
    return pyodide.runPython(command);
}

function arrayToPyBytes(array) {
    let result = bytes(array.byteLength);
    let result_buffer = result.getBuffer("u8");
    result_buffer.data.set(array);
    result_buffer.release();
    return result;
}

function pyBytesToArray(pyBytes) {
    let result = pyBytes.getBuffer("u8");
    pyBytes.destroy();
    return result;
}

export {pyodide, pip, run, micropip, bytes, lzma, hashlib, load, arrayToPyBytes, pyBytesToArray}
```

Запуская сервер и переходя на сайт получаю в консоле следующее:

```
Загрузка модуля по адресу «http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/download.js» была заблокирована из-за неразрешенного MIME-типа («text/plain»).
8902
Загрузка модуля по адресу «http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/download.js» не удалась.
```

`type="module"` в `<script type="module" src"...">` обязательно, иначе пишет, что импорты вне модуля запрещены(делал по примеру FF: https://github.com/mdn/js-examples/tree/master/module-examples/basic-modules)
Как это можно исправить?
(Ошибка странная не проявляется на моём пк, но при запуске сервера точно также на другом пк, получаю в консоле эту ошибку.)

udp:
Насколько я понимаю, косяк возможно во flask, но как это исправить?